# how to use eclipse project variables in code

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I would like to get the values of eclipse project variables such as **$(PROJECT_LOC)**, **$(PARENT_LOC)** in my c++ code. How could i access the variables from code?

Comment: I don't know if it's allowed by Eclipse, but you could try making a preprocessor macro in the project settings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do it this way.Hope this will help you.

  `your c++ project->properties->C/C++ General->Path and Symbols.`
- In that you will find one column called `Symbol`.In that select **GNU C++** and add your variable/macro.

Comment: There is a tricky problem associated with your solution. If i use those macros, it will be preprocessed into text without double quotes in code, which will result in error. How to use the symbol as a string?

Comment: The problem was with eclipse. Whenever i define the symbol as \"$(PROJECT_LOC)\", the terminating quote was removed automatically. So i have added a extra quote at the end like \"$(PROJECT_LOC)\"". Refer this [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309158).